# Problem with opencv on creating Android App with Kivy and Buildozer: /site-packages/cv2/cv2.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit, targetsdk: 27

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, buildozer

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit for creating an Android App using kivy,opencv and buildozer.
Opencv is imported in .py file as:

```py
import cv2
```

and the requirement is added in buildozer.spec as:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,numpy,opencv
```

Python 3.6 is used for this project.

I am able to successfully build using buildozer but on running the app on android, the screen just flashes and close immediately.

On checking "adb logcat" I got the following error:

```
**06-30 15:18:03.487 22313 22990 W linker  : dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.solvescan/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit, targetsdk: 27, retry**
```

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Your opencv is probably compiled for the desktop rather than for Android. Perhaps this is a bug with python-for-android. Did you make any other build attempts before this one, e.g. putting python-opencv instead of just opencv in the requirements, as this would be a mistake that could cause this type of error.

Comment: Ya i had used python-opencv before and then tried with opencv. What could be solution for this?

Comment: Clean all the build then run again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **python 3.6** then instead of

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,numpy,opencv
```

use

```
requirements = hostpython3==3.7.5,python3==3.6,kivy,kivymd,numpy,opencv
```

[Check this for reference](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1090#issuecomment-626846405)

Hope this helps you **:)**